# cakephp 3 patch store extra column data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 3 tables:

```
Users, Groups and Groups_Users.
```

In the groups_users, the columns are:

```
id
group_id
user_id
lead
```

I already can add the group and user id in the column, but when I try to edit the group and a user is already added to it, I want to be able to make a user group lead, by ticking a checkbox.

But that boolean is not being stored.

Here is what I have for the edit code:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');
    $group = $this->Groups->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $group = $this->Groups->patchEntity($group, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Groups->save($group)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The group has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The group could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('group'));
}
```

Am I missing anything?

By the way, in the debug data, I see the `id, group_id, user_id, lead as _joinData.`

**Update**

I have added the following code to the edit template:

```
$this->Form->control('users.'.$counter.'._joinData.lead');
```

$counter is a counter.

And in the controller:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');
    $group = $this->Groups->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $group = $this->Groups->patchEntity($group, $this->request->getData(), [
            'associated' => [
                'Users'
            ]
        ]);
        if ($this->Groups->save($group)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The group has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The group could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('group'));
}
```

Comment: Read https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-additional-data-to-the-join-table

Comment: @Salines thanks it does "work", however it also changes the user_id, which should not happen, do I miss anything?